# Unrecognized selector sent to instance on custom object

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, unrecognized-selector

I created a custom class object Action with three enums as instance variables:

```
@interface Action : NSObject  <NSCopying>

@property ImageSide imageSide; //typedef enum 
@property EyeSide eyeSide; //typedef enum 
@property PointType pointType;  //typedef enum
@property int actionId;

- (id) initWithType:(int)num eyeSide:(EyeSide)eyes type:(PointType)type imageSide:(ImageSide)image;

@end
```

With this implementation:

```
@implementation Action
@synthesize imageSide;
@synthesize eyeSide;
@synthesize pointType;
@synthesize actionId;

- (id) initWithType:(int)num eyeSide:(EyeSide)eyes type:(PointType)type imageSide:(ImageSide)image {    
    // Call superclass's initializer
    self = [super init];
    if( !self ) return nil;

    actionId = num;
    imageSide = image;
    eyeSide = eyes;
    pointType = type;

    return self;
}
@end
```

And in my ViewController, I try to add it as a key to a NSMutableDictionary object, like this:

```
   Action* currentAction = [[Action alloc] initWithType:0 eyeSide:right type:eye imageSide:top];
    pointsDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:20];
    [pointsDict setObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(touchCoordinates.x, touchCoordinates.y)] forKey:currentAction];
```

However, I get this error, when setObject is called:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Action copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I went through some answers in SO related to this error, but no one seems to solve this problem, and as I am new to iOS development I'm quite puzzled by this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare your `Action` class to conform to the `NSCopying` protocol.

So you need to implement `-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone` for that class.

Answer (score 1):

The Object you use as a a key in your mutable dictionnary must conform the `NSCopying` protocol (So `copyWithZone:` must be implemented) as decribed in the Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

In your case, you declare the object as corresponding the the `NSCopying` protocol but you don't implement the method. You need to.

Hope this helps